# What are the downsides/cons of passing an object of dependencies throughout a Node.js app versus importing?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've done allot of reading and video watching on the topic of dependency injection in a Node.js application and I am yet to find the answer to this question:

***What are the downsides/cons of passing an object of dependencies throughout a Node.js app versus importing?***

Lets say in my index.js file I import 10 modules:

```
const module1 = require('module1')
const module2 = require('module2')
const module3 = require('module3')
...
const doSomeWork = require('./doSomeWork')
```

I then add these modules to an object:

```
const deps = {
  module1,
  module2,
  module3,
  ...
}
```

Lets say I call an imported function in my index.js file called `doSomeWork()`. `doSomeWork` requires `module2`. I could import `module2` in the `doSomeWork` file, or I could call `doSomeWork(deps)` and pass in the deps object. Passing in deps makes it easier to test `doSomeWork`, since if `module2` was a database module, I could mock up a fake DB.

So I am wondering, what are the downsides/cons to importing all the modules your app needs in your root `index` file for example and passing a deps object to the different components that need those modules?

Are there performance hits, will I loose out on some module benefits of importing I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **against** passing the dependencies from your `index.js` into dependencies. Specialized modules like `sinon` provide [stubs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.7/stubs/) which can override `require()`-d dependencies for your unit testing pleasure. Managing the dependency tree yourself will more likely cause you more headaches than you will save since you will have an additional step in interfacing with any existing javascript API.

In addition, your `index.js` will likely become monolithic and hard to decipher. `require()` calls have some caching behavior, so you should not worry about a performance hit on repeated calls. There are likely larger performance hits to your program than `require()` calls on initialization.